# Logarithmic Depth Buffer OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, depth-buffer

I've managed to implement a logarithmic depth buffer in OpenGL, mainly courtesy of articles from [Outerra](http://outerra.blogspot.ca/) (You can read them [here](http://outerra.blogspot.ca/2009/08/logarithmic-z-buffer.html), [here](http://outerra.blogspot.ca/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html), and [here](http://outerra.blogspot.ca/2013/07/logarithmic-depth-buffer-optimizations.html)).  However, I'm having some issues, and I'm not sure if these issues are inherent to using a logarithmic depth buffer or if there's some workaround I can't think of.

Just to start off, this is how I calculate logarithmic depth within the vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = MVP * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
gl_Position.z = log2(max(ZNEAR, 1.0 + gl_Position.w)) * FCOEF - 1.0;
flogz = 1.0 + gl_Position.w;
```

And this is how I fix depth values in the fragment shader:

```
gl_FragDepth = log2(flogz) * HALF_FCOEF;
```

Where `ZNEAR = 0.0001`, `ZFAR = 1000000.0`, `FCOEF = 2.0 / log2(ZFAR + 1.0)`, and `HALF_FCOEF = 0.5 * FCOEF`.  `C`, in my case, is 1.0, to simplify my code and reduce calculations.

For starters, I'm extremely pleased with the level of precision I get.  With normal depth buffering (znear = 0.1, zfar = 1000.0), I get quite a bit of z-fighting towards the edge of the view distance.  Right now, with my MUCH further znear:zfar, I've put a second ground plane 0.01 units below the first, and I cannot find any z-fighting, no matter how far I zoom the camera out (I get a little z-fighting when it's only 0.0001 (0.1 mm) away, but meh).

I do have some issues/concerns, however.

1) I get more near-plane clipping than I did with my normal depth buffer, and it looks ugly.  It happens in cases where, logically, it really shouldn't.  Here are a couple of screenshots of what I mean:

Clipping the ground.

[image: Clipping the ground.]

Clipping a mesh.

[image: Clipping a mesh.]

Both of these cases are things that I did not experience with my normal depth buffer, and I'd rather not see (especially the former).  EDIT:  Problem 1 is officially solved by using `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP)`.

2) In order to get this to work, I need to write to gl_FragDepth.  I tried not doing so, but the results were unacceptable.  Writing to gl_FragDepth means that my graphics card can't do early z optimizations.  This will inevitably drive me up the wall and so I want to fix it as soon as I can.

3) I need to be able to retrieve the value stored in the depth buffer (I already have a framebuffer and texture for this), and then convert it to a linear view-space co-ordinate.  I don't really know where to start with this, the way I did it before involved the inverse projection matrix but I can't really do that here.  Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Near plane clipping happens independently from depth testing, but by clipping against the *cli space volume*. In modern OpenGL one can use *depth clamping* to make things look nice again. See http://opengl.datenwolf.net/gltut/html/Positioning/Tut05%20Depth%20Clamping.html#d0e5707

Comment: I hereby declare problem #1 officially solved!  Thank you very much!  Do I have to worry about depth clamping reducing the available precision?

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach: No, depth clamping does not limit precision. It just forces all fragments that would be "nearer" than the near clip plane to lie exactly on the clip plane. Of course this clashes with depth testing, since every fragment closer than near will then pass the depth test (if less-equal is used) or just the first one (if just less is used).

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach: Oh, and you no longer have to write to gl_FragDepth with clamping. Regarding 3) when you read the depth value back and linearize them, for everythign being clipped you'll get them back lying in the near plane.

Comment: would that mess up my deferred shading renderer that relies on the depth buffer to reconstruct view-space position?

Comment: I tried rendering without writing to gl_FragDepth but I'm still getting the very unacceptable errors.

Comment: The link is unavailable.

Comment: @Dudeson: thanks for the heads up. Since the original site went down a couple of months ago I made a mirror. I updated the question with the link on my mirror.

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

1) In the equation you used:
  gl_Position.z = log2(max(ZNEAR, 1.0 + gl_Position.w)) * FCOEF - 1.0;
There should not be ZNEAR, because that's unrelated to it. The constant there is just to avoid log2 argument to be zero, e.g you can use 1e-6 there.

But otherwise the depth clamping will solve the issue.

2) You can avoid using gl_FragDepth only with adaptive tesselation, that keeps the interpolation error in bounds. For example, in Outerra the terrain is adaptively tesselated, and thus it never happens that there would be a visible error on the terrain. But the fragment depth write is needed on the objects when zooming in close, as the long screen-space triangles will have the discrepancy between linearly interpolated value and the correct logarithmic value quite high.

Note that latest AMD drivers now support the [NV_depth_buffer_float](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/depth_buffer_float.txt) extension, so it's now possible to use the [Reversed floating-point depth buffer](http://outerra.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html) setup instead. It's not yet supported on Intel GPUs though, as far as I know.

3) The conversion to the view space depth is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18187212/2435594

Comment: 1) I tried using 1e-6, 1e-1, 1, etc, instead of ZNEAR, but I pretty much get the same problem no matter what I put in.  Ironically, 1e-6 gives me more error than 1e-1 does.  I just used ZNEAR because it's a constant I defined and generally prefer to use constants than magic numbers.   2) Good to note, but I can't really tesselate all of my geometry.  Walls and such tend to be large polygons, and I can't expect all of my users to have tessellation shaders available.  I considered using the reversed floating-point depth buffer, but it's only viable if I can use it with a stencil buffer (cont.)

Comment: without wasting 24 bits.   3) Thank you!

Comment: regarding 3), the formula posted did work for me.  When I rendered both (`fragColor = vec4(reconstructedDepth, positionBuffer.z, 0.0, 1.0);`) I get uniform yellow across the majority of the scene, which is what I expect to see with correct results, EXCEPT for things which are very close to the camera, which appear more red.  I suspect that depth clamping might have something to do with this.

Comment: Looks like I spoke to soon, when I compare it more properly (`0.5 + (reconstructedDepth - positionBuffer.z)`), the scene looks very white (meaning the reconstructed depth has a much higher value than the actual depth).

Comment: On all modern cards the depth and stencil data are separate, and the OpenGL identifier that suggests the padding is historic & now misleading.

Comment: Did you change the sign on the reconstructedDepth?

Comment: I didn't change the sign on reconstructedDepth, but I did change the sign on positionBuffer.z (I set it to `vec3(positionBuffer.xy, -(positionBuffer.z + 1.0)` which produces something I can actually see (since z values are normally negative)).

Comment: That +1.0 there suggests you are expecting/comparing clip-space values, right? But the reverse provides a camera-space depth, i.e. the physical depth in world-space units.

Comment: To be honest, the +1.0 suggests that I tinkered with it until I produced something visible.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late for answering.
In any case, to reconstruct Z usign the log2 version:

```
realDepth = pow(2,(LogDepthValue + 1.0)/Fcoef) - 1.0;
```