# How to un-linearize the depth buffer value

Tags: opengl, glsl, algebra, inverse, depth-buffer

I use this function to linearize the depth value in my shaders:

```c
float linearize_depth(float d, float zNear, float zFar)
{
    return zNear * zFar / (zFar + d * (zNear - zFar));
}
```

What function would do the exact inverse transformation?

Answer (score 0):

With logarithmic depth buffer, the mapping of scene (camera space) depth to values that ultimately end up in the depth buffer (0..1) is:

> depth_value = log(C*z + 1) / log(C*Far + 1)

where z is the positive depth into the scene, otherwise obtainable from the w component in clip space after the projection (in your code you can use ..log(clip.w + 1.0)..).

To retrieve the camera space depth in a fragment shader, the equation needs to be inverted:

> z = (exp(depth_value*log(C*far+1)) - 1)/C

or equivalently

> z = (pow(C*far+1,depth_value)-1)/C

To get a linear mapping from 0..far into a 0..1, just divide it by the far value.

Credit goes to [camenomizoratojoakizunewake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435594/camenomizoratojoakizunewake).
Original answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18187212/14887913).